# Problem with Bluetooth headphone

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I got a bluetooth headphone with microphone and when i configure the sound profile as A2DP the audio works but the microphone does not work. When i configure the sound profile as HSP/HFP, my microphone is recognized but both stop working (mic doesn't work and I can only hear static). If I open youtube the video doesn't load). Some one can help me?

Comment: Whats your setup? Which wireless card do you have in your system? I have the same problem on my 20.04 using an intel AX201.